# Issue displaying images on google collaborator, white lines are appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have an issue displaying images on google collaborator. As you can see on below images some white lines are appearing on the middle of the image as a grid. How can I eliminate this behaviour? I was loocking for a solution but I do not find anything related.

[image]
[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't posted any actual examples of your plotting code, so who knows, but it seems like you may have the global `'axes.grid'` option set to `True`. You can turn it off by running:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False
```

Comment: That's it. I did not post any code because I was not doing anything special. I Read the image, plt.imshow() plt.show(). It is seems that in colab this option is set true by default.Thanks for your help!

Comment: When asking questions on SO, it's always a good idea to post a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that's causing your problem. You're just lucky that I was able to blindly guess your problem in this case.